# How to change a normal method to a static method in an inherited class in c++?

Tags: c++

Exist a way to change a method of a base class, to be the same method but just with the modifier static?

I'm searching in all the questions but only find the inverse question (static to non static). My "solution" until now, was to copy and paste all the method in the derivated class but with the static modifier.

Exist a simple way to do that?

Here an example code:

```
Class A {
  protected:
  static int a;
  
  public:
  bool method(){
    //do something with a, and other things.
  }
};

Class B : public A {
  
  public:
  static bool method(){
    //Exactly the same method of the base class, but need to be static
  }
};
```

Thank you

**EDIT:**
I need to change the method to static, because Im using it in another static method (that work without any instance) and is necesary to use only static members in a static method.

Comment: Can you give a little more detail on why you want to do this? The smells of [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040).

Comment: What's your use case / goal with doing that? Can you elaborate [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64473084/edit) please?

Comment: Do you just want to reuse the name as an overload?

Comment: No, there is no way to do this. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: I am confused how the implementations would be the same between a static function and a non static member. Does the non static version only access static members? If that is the case why isn't it a static already?

Comment: In `B` you could technically do `static bool method() { return A().method(); }`. It will compile, though it doesn't make much sense. But then the question itself doesn't make much sense without any context or details provided.

Comment: Thank you all (@ShadowRanger@πάνταῥεῖ @Zan @Sam @drescherjm @dxiv)f or the fast response. The reason because im trying to do that is the Class `A` is already implemented, and im adding a several features to a new derivated Class `B`.

Comment: Yes @drescherjm the non static method only access static members.

Comment: @dxiv It does not work, because `A::method()` is not static, so is impossible to call the method without an instance of the class.

Comment: @Fabrizio [Try it](https://godbolt.org/z/Yjx97r). `A()` creates an instance of `A` which calls `method`. Of course it's wasteful and indicates deeper design problems, but it *does* compile.

Comment: @dxiv oh ok, I understand, sorry for the misunderstanding. And with this "solution" the static members of the instance of class `A`, are the same of the derivated class `B`?  Thank you for the fast response man.

Comment: @Fabrizio Yes, nothing in the inheritance is affected by the "peculiar" implementation of `B::method`.

Comment: @dxiv thank you. If I knew how to place your comment as an answer, I would place it and add +1.

Comment: Unlike other languages, C++ allows you to call static methods from the class instance as (somewhat) a normal member function. Why not declare it static both in base and derived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-static method must be called on an actual object. Here, this can be done in one of two ways.

- Create a temporary `A` object when calling `A::method`.

  ```
  class B : public A {
    public:
    static bool method(){
      return A().method();
    }
  };
  ```
- Define a dummy `A` object (otherwise unused) just for calling `A::method`.

  ```
  class B : public A {
    static A a;
    public:
    static bool method(){
      return a.method();
    }
  };
  ```

Under the assumption stated by the OP in a comment that `A::method` "*only accesses static members*" the two implementations would be functionally equivalent as far as `B::method` goes.

While either of the above will technically work, fact remains that it is poor design for `class A` to implement as non-static a non-virtual function that does not use any non-static members.

Comment: Just for completeness, a horrible [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) hack that might still work (under the same assumptions) with many compiler implementations could be `static bool method() { return ((A *)NULL)->method(); }`.